Setting up passthrough proxy for S3 PUT/POST call
I am facing a unique situation while attempting to upload files to an S3 bucket using multipart upload through a passthrough proxy. My Web UI uses AWS SDK v3 with Access Key to perform the upload. Due to network limitations, I need to set up a proxy to replace the regional S3 bucket URL.
Original Flow: The UI makes a POST request to the endpoint https://mybucket-name.s3.region.amazonaws.com/test_key/file_name/?uploads=&x-id=CreateMultipartUpload
New Flow with Proxy: I have set up an AWS CloudFront distribution to serve as the passthrough proxy. Now, the UI calls: https://xxxxxxxx.cloudfront.net/test_key/file_name/?uploads=&x-id=CreateMultipartUpload
CloudFront Setup
Origin Type: S3 bucket with origin domain set to mybucket-name.region.amazonaws.com.
Behaviors:

HTTPS-only policy.

Allowed methods: GET, HEAD, OPTIONS, PUT, POST, PATCH, DELETE.


Cache Policy: Disabled caching.
Origin Request Policy: Customized to:

Include all viewer headers.

Exclude cookies.

Include all query strings.


Access Control: Did not configure Origin Access Control (OAC), relying on the Access Key for permissions.
Problems Encountered
CORS Issues:

I believe the issue is due to a missing response policy in CloudFront. To bypass this temporarily, I disabled web security in the browser.

Upload Failure with 404 Error

When making a POST request to the CloudFront URL: https://xxxxxxxx.cloudfront.net/test_key/file_name/?uploads=&x-id=CreateMultipartUploadI receive a 404 Not Found error.

Modifying the Access Key or Session Token results in SignatureDoesNotMatch or InvalidToken errors, which indicates that the request probably is being forwarded to the S3 bucket successfully.


I’d appreciate insights or suggestions on:

If there's a better way to set up this passthrough proxy using CloudFront for S3 uploads.

Diagnosing the root cause of the 404 Not Found error.

Whether additional configuration is required for CORS or Origin Access Control (OAC).


